# Error loading tidyverse after fresh install - R (loadNamespace, broom, backports)

Tags: r, tidyverse

I just updated R to version 4.0.2 and updated RStudio Desktop to version 1.3.959. As seen in the code below, I am **unable to load tidyverse** after what appears to be a successful installation. However, data.table installs and loads perfectly fine. Does anyone have experience with this? Thanks!

Code from console (tidyverse error):

```
> install.packages('tidyverse')
Installing package into ‘C:/Users/iangm/Documents/R/win-library/4.0’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
also installing the dependencies ‘RColorBrewer’, ‘scales’, ‘dplyr’, ‘ggplot2’

trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/4.0/RColorBrewer_1.1-2.zip'
Content type 'application/zip' length 55583 bytes (54 KB)
downloaded 54 KB

trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/4.0/scales_1.1.1.zip'
Content type 'application/zip' length 560984 bytes (547 KB)
downloaded 547 KB

trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/4.0/dplyr_1.0.0.zip'
Content type 'application/zip' length 1302777 bytes (1.2 MB)
downloaded 1.2 MB

trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/4.0/ggplot2_3.3.2.zip'
Content type 'application/zip' length 4068169 bytes (3.9 MB)
downloaded 3.9 MB

trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/4.0/tidyverse_1.3.0.zip'
Content type 'application/zip' length 440050 bytes (429 KB)
downloaded 429 KB

package ‘RColorBrewer’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
package ‘scales’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
package ‘dplyr’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
package ‘ggplot2’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
package ‘tidyverse’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked

The downloaded binary packages are in
    C:\Users\iangm\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpkNazQW\downloaded_packages
> library(tidyverse)
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘tidyverse’:
 .onLoad failed in loadNamespace() for 'broom', details:
  call: loadNamespace(name)
  error: there is no package called ‘backports’
```

Code from console (data.table success):

```
> install.packages('data.table')
Installing package into ‘C:/Users/iangm/Documents/R/win-library/4.0’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/4.0/data.table_1.12.8.zip'
Content type 'application/zip' length 2325868 bytes (2.2 MB)
downloaded 2.2 MB

package ‘data.table’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked

The downloaded binary packages are in
    C:\Users\iangm\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpkNazQW\downloaded_packages
> library(data.table)
data.table 1.12.8 using 2 threads (see ?getDTthreads).  Latest news: r-datatable.com
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There can be some problem with package `backports`: try to reinstall that package and load tidyverse again:

```
install.packages("backports")
library(tidyverse)
```

If that doesn't work, there might be problem with packages built under an earlier major version of R (i.e. 3.x). Try reinstalling all the packages with:

```
update.packages(ask = FALSE, checkBuilt = TRUE)
```

See more info here:

- [Is there a way to automate reinstalling packages and their dependencies in r?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62117903/is-there-a-way-to-automate-reinstalling-packages-and-their-dependencies-in-r)

Comment: Thanks for the help! Installing the package `backports` helped me get to the solution. When installing `backports` I had to choose "no" on the prompt asking if I wanted to install from source. Installing from source led to the same error I posted above. Running `library(tidyverse)` then gave an error regarding the package `fs`, so I had to also install the package `fs`, similarly not from source.

Comment: @IanMalone Thanks, great, I'm glad it works for you! Installing binary versions of packages really seems to be the safer way (rather than the source).